# How can you determine the direction of the polarizing axis of a single polarizer?

Tags: optics

How can you determine the direction of the polarizing axis
of a single polarizer?

Answer (score 3):

You have to have a second polarizing device that you can use to analyze the polarization.

A common choice is to use a reflection from water or a glossy floor that happens to lie near [Brewster's angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brewster%27s_angle), which makes the light strongly polarized in the plane of the reflecting surface.  Look through your polarizer at the reflections, and rotate your polarizer until the reflections vanish: that's your polarizer's vertical axis (assuming your floor was horizontal).

Comment: Slightly pedantic but one could also use a pre-characterized light source which is linearly polarized in some intrinsic way. E.g., the laser gain in some anisotropic crystals can be polarization dependent.